# Why does PostgreSQL's \dt show only public schema tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a new schema in my PostgreSQl database with psql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
```

But when I issue the `\dt` command, I see only the tables that are in the `public` schema. However, I can access all the tables in `my_schema` with `my_schema.table_name`.

How can I see all the tables from all the schemas in psql?

Comment: Try `\dt *.*` after `\c your_db_name`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

For your schema (*note the period after the schema name*):

```
\dt my_schema.
```

Or:

```
SET search_path TO my_schema, public;
\dt
```

For all schemas:

```
\dt *.*
```

Comment: Just what I needed (once I realized there was a dot there).  Cheers!

Comment: In a script, using **SET search_path TO schema_name;** worked for me, without the ```\dt```

Comment: Right, the \dt there is just an example to list the tables in the selected schema.

Comment: `\dt *.*` worked for me, `\dt *.` did not.

Comment: likewise, `\dt my_schema.*` worked for me, but `\dt my_schema.` did not.