# PostgreSQL - relation [table] does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I just created a new user that I want to have access to a limited number of our public tables. The user is created and I granted privs to one public table for now. I then logged into the DB as that user and tried to run a SELECT on the table that the user should be able to get to but I must of missed a step or did something wrong because when I run the query I get:

**relation [table] does not exist**

Below are the steps I took, in order.

```
CREATE USER pqb2b WITH PASSWORD 'foo'


 select * from pg_user;
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd |  passwd   | valuntil | useconfig
 ----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+----         |
postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t         | ******** |          | 
 pgb2b   | 17267767 | t           | f        | f         | ******** | infinity |
```

(1 rows)

```
GRANT ALL on b_users to pgb2b;



SELECT
schemaname||'.'||tablename
FROM
pg_tables
WHERE
has_table_privilege (
    'pgb2b',
    schemaname||'.'||tablename,
    'select'
 )
AND
schemaname NOT IN (
    'pg_catalog',
    'information_schema'
 );
```

---

```
public.b_users
(1 row)



~ postgres$ psql -U pgb2b  mydb
psql (9.0.3)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=> select * from b_users;
ERROR:  relation "b_users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from b_users;

 mydb=> \d+ b_users
 Did not find any relation named "b_users".
```

Comment: did you specify a schema?

Comment: I don't think so. Just what I posted above.

Comment: oh, nevermind, I didn't notice it was in the public schema.

Comment: You must've edited that log; you ran `select * from users` and got `relation b_users does not exist`. Can you please show **original and unedited** logs? If the above is in fact unedited, please show the output of `\d+ users` and `\d+ b_users`.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo from my copy and paste. I fixed the typo and added the additional output in my queston

Comment: Were you in the correct database when you ran you grant stuff?

Comment: Yes, I was logged in as postgres user

Answer (score 18):

Even though I was granting privileges to my pgb2b user, I forgot to specify usage for that user:

```
GRANT usage on schema public to pgb2b;
```

This fixed the issue. I found this [post](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/permission-denied-for-schema-error-337648.html) about setting up PostgreSQL user permissions very helpful.

Comment: am getting this error ```ERROR: role "pgb2b" does not exist
SQL state: 42704```

Answer (score 3):

Note for others who may see this, though it may not apply to this particular question --

If you are **not using the public schema**, you need to update the search_path

```
SET search_path TO my_schema, public;
```

Credit: [Why does PostgreSQL's \dt show only public schema tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931883/why-does-postgresqls-dt-show-only-public-schema-tables)