# Incorrect syntax error "as" Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am postgres here is my query

```
update cust_final_1 as cust set cust.enure_days=datediff(day,1date,current_date)
from  card as card join  cust_final_1 as cust on cust.cust_id=card.cardh_cust_id
left join bt_time as tim on card.cardh_act_dt=tim.time_id
```

on executing it gives error as incorrect syntax near "as"

What the mistake

Comment: This isn't Postgres syntax.  `datediff()` is not a Postgres function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE cust
SET cust.enure_days = datediff(day, 1 DATE, CURRENT_DATE)
FROM card AS card
INNER JOIN cust_final_1 AS cust
    ON cust.cust_id = card.cardh_cust_id
LEFT JOIN bt_time AS tim
    ON card.cardh_act_dt = tim.time_id
```

Just replace the table name with the alias, right after the `UPDATE` keyword

Comment: it gave this err `ERROR: relation "cust" does not exist`

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna Did you test this code in your application or directly in the Postgres command line? I believe this isn't a problem with the SQL code, but with something in your application. (table references or something) - do a simple web search (this is just an example of what I found : [Possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489105/postgresql-relation-table-does-not-exist))

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I suspect he didn't change the table name from "cust" to "cust_final_1". Anyway - I don't think datediff is valid Postgresql syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your columns mean, but here goes. I assume "1date" is the date you want the difference from

```
UPDATE cust_final_1 
SET enure_days=current_date - "1date" -- datediff is not postgresql, just subtract if they are both dates
FROM card 
left join bt_time as tim on card.cardh_act_dt=tim.time_id
WHERE cust_final_1.cust_id=card.cardh_cust_id
```

I'm also suspicious of the left join. Why do that? If there is no corresponding record in bt_time and "1date" is in that table, you're updating the record with NULL. I'd suggest using an INNER JOIN, which will just mean that missing records don't do anything.